# insert an HTML code in a Cell using PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, html, phpspreadsheet

Is there a way to insert an HTML code into a Cell using PhpSpreadsheet?
For example this code :

```
<font color="red">Hello World!</font>
```

This HTML already giving the text a style without going through the pre-defined PhpSpreadsheet's style functions.

Answer (score 3):

The solution already exist:
You just need to add the following :

```
$CODE = '<font color="red">Hello World!</font>';
$html = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Helper\Html();
$HTMLCODE = $html->toRichTextObject($CODE);
```